# How to make the Java runtime use OS CA certchain?

Tags: java

For instance, usually I manage certchain on RHEL with `yum update ca-certificates`. How do I ensure that Java always includes these certchains into its runtime keystore? Is there any way to enforce this across all Java runtimes on a server

An example for clarity

Java stores its root CA in $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts. The OS typically stores its certificates elsewhere. Ubuntu uses /etc/ssl/certs. RHEL uses /etc/pki/ca-trust/.

Obviously this is pretty annoying since if you need to integrate an internal CA, you have to update every Java runtime on every server. I want to know if there is a simple way to make Java use both its own cacerts and the OS cacerts.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more precise and provide more details here? Which environment(s) are you talking of exactly? How comes there are several java runtimes installed on "a server"? I really cannot figure out what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: @cyberbrain there is no need for precision. 

This is a very straightforward question. It could be any linux environment but lets say rhel8 for now.  

Why are there several java runtimes on a server? Because it runs apps on different versions.

Comment: java stores its root CA in $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts. The OS typically stores its certificates elsewhere. Ubuntu uses /etc/ssl/certs. RHEL uses /etc/pki/ca-trust/.

Comment: Obviously this is pretty annoying since if you need to integrate an internal CA, you have to update every java runtime on every server. I want to know if It can be unified

Comment: **IF you use the RHEL package(s)** for OpenJDK (or other RH family such as CentOS or Scientific) then $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts is a symlink to the data maintained by the `ca-certificates` package in `/etc/pki`. Similarly for Debian family such as Ubuntu. If you use other Java builds/packages it depends on the builder or packager. But there are other OSes besides Linux, and some of them don't have a truststore in a file Java can use, or even at all.

Comment: The short answer is No.  There isn't a way that you can enforce this for all Java runtimes installed on a server.  And since "best practice" is really just opinion dressed up with a fancy hat ... you are actually asking for opinions, which is off-topic.